# Android Studio Manifest file error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

Something went wrong with my AndroidManifest.xml file. I was launching tests one more time when suddenly Android Studio crashed, launched again and then next error occured (I'm sorry, I don't have enough rating to upload pictures directly):
[image]

Here is the gradle console:
[image]

My strings.xml file is ok:

```
<resources>
<string title="app_name">PaySpaceMagazine</string>
<string title="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string title="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string title="actual">Актуально</string>
<string title="last_news">Последние известия</string>
```

Also there is other manifest file without any errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Did anyone have same problem?

Comment: As the error suggests, you are missing `android:name` for the activity in your manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Manifest you posted in the screenshot you are using `android:title` instead of `android:name` for your `Activity`s. Change it with

```
 android:name=".MainActivity"
```

the property is mandatory. You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm)

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Try changing your manifest file to this

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem its not pulling from the string it should be showing the app name

*android:label="@string/app_name"*

the easiest solution create new app proyect open manifest copy that line make user not to press it or you will break string again paste line over your broken string if you want change name go to the strings xml change name there